# Navigation bar is overlapping the UIView [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

In the picture below, the navigation bar is overlapping the cardview. The whole screen is basically a view from a tab bar. On top is a `navigationItem(the green one)`, then the `navigationBar(the red one)` and then the `CardView`.The `translucent propery` is set to `false` for the `navigationBar` but the `CardView` is still overlapped. I have unchecked the `extendedLayout property` to but that doesn't have any effect either.

Is there something else I can do to place the `CardView` below the navigationBar with padding?

[image]

Comment: Do you mean your view is behind the navigation bar?

Comment: It's being overlapped. I need to place it below the navigation bar

Comment: Try `edgesForExtendedLayout = []` in `viewDidLoad()`.

Comment: I did. Doesn't work

Comment: If it ia a Scroll/Collection/TableView, try to un-tick `Adjust Scroll View Insets` in Storyboard.

Comment: No, it's just a normal UIView. But I still tried the `Scroll View Insets` but to no avail

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130704/discussion-between-user782400-and-shallowthought).

Comment: Are you using autoLayout or setting Frame? Are you using IB or doing it from code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the constraint on the top of the card view to the bottom of the top layout guide.